# How to add items to combobox in WPF which is bound to datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

When I try to add item to combobox in WPF which is already bound I get an error. How to achieve this ? My target is to add default value to the combobox.

KINDLY HELP.

```
    public static void BindControl(ref ComboBox obj, DataTable DT, String key, String value, String defaultvalue)
            {                  
                try
                {
                    if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {                   
                            obj.DataContext = DT;
                            obj.SelectedValuePath = DT.Columns[value].ColumnName;
                            obj.DisplayMemberPath = DT.Columns[key].ColumnName;        
                            obj.SelectedIndex = 0;


                            ComboBoxItem x = new ComboBoxItem();
                            x.Content = defaultvalue;
                            obj.Items.Add(x);
                            obj.Items.Insert(0, x); //THIS THROWS ERROR
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `Items` into the DataTable.